# Vitest, callback not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, unit-testing, vitest

I am trying to test a function that uses a callback.
It looks something like this:

```js
export const foo = (data, callback) => {
   response = await callback();
   // based on response and data return value
   // ...

   return value;
}
```

I am testing it as such:

```js
import { it, describe, expect, vi } from "vitest";
import { foo } from "../path/to/foo";

describe("foo",() => {
  const data = {data: [0, 1, 2]};
  const mockResponse = {response: [3, 4, 5]};

  const mockCallback = vi.fn(() => mockResponse);
  const mockCallback2 = () => mockResponse; // this yields the same results

  it("should call mockCallback once", async () => {
    await foo(data, mockCallback);
    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }); // this fails: expected "spy" to be called 1 times, but got 0 times

  it("should have the correct output", async () => {
    const output = await foo(data, mockCallback);
    expect(output).toEqual("Some correct value: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"); 
  }); // this fails too
});
```

I have tested the behavior without vitest with a fake function callback that simply returns the desired response value and it works as expected, but I do not know why the callback is ignored.

What am I doing wrong? Or what would be the correct way of testing this?